# Overriding "View" button of the standard Quote object

Tags: visualforce, quote, button-overrides

After developing a page to override the default `View` button of the standard `Quote` object, I noticed this is one of the only object that do not allow this possibility (or the only one?). I'm not quite sure why, but I'm not the only one who faced that reality:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IhSL

Is there a tweak / workaround that could allow me to add this behaviour or emulate it? I thought of an included Visualforce with a redirect, but this is definitely a too dirty alternative to be even considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise against trying to override the Quote View.

I found a way to hack my way into making it happen, but it broke the built-in Quote functionality due to cross-site scripting errors.

The Quote page has a button to generate PDF attachments from the Quote... this executes some JavaScript served from the main Salesforce servers. If that code is executed from a Visualforce server, it will fall foul of XSS restrictions.

So my solution (still dirty) was to use a Home Page Component with JavaScript in it to customise the Quote View in the way that I needed. Like this:

http://www.cloudsherpas.com/partner-salesforce/salesforce-tips-querying-and-manipulating-data-from-the-sidebar/

Comment: Well I have a custom `Quote Line Items` related list to display (in Visualforce). Including it in the layout won't make it, considering that it has a variable height and I don't want it to look super messy. Also, I'm not quite sure I can include Visualforce using the sidebar hack: it will most likely still end up being a clunky / unflexible `iframe` being inserted to the DOM. Am I right?

Comment: If you add a Visualforce page to the page layout, that ends up being implemented as an iFrame, styled to look seamless. Having that at a fixed height is going to be your quickest solution.